# Create font from image

Tags: fonts, images

How can I manually or automatically create a .ttf or .otf font from the following image?

[image: The image]

Comment: It's probably a lot simpler to google for an 80s game font

Comment: I really need to create a font from this particular image. I'm ready to go through all the trouble, even if it means learning to use some software.